# Stop player movement when releasing a key

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am making a game in Java, and I am working on player movement, but whenever a press a directional key, the player moves but doesn't stop when I release the key.

I can't seem to see what I am doing wrong. May someone point me in the right direction?

// Input class implements KeyListener

```
public static final int LEFT    = 0;
public static final int RIGHT   = 1;
public static final int UP  = 2;
public static final int DOWN    = 3;

public boolean[] keys = new boolean[64];

public void getKeys(KeyEvent e, boolean move) {
    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        keys[LEFT]  = move;
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: 
        keys[RIGHT] = move; 
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP: 
        keys[UP]    = move; 
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: 
        keys[DOWN]  = move; 
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE: 
        keys[BQUOTE] = move; 
        break;
    }

    keys[OTHER] = move;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    getKeys(e, true);

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    getKeys(e, false);

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

// Player Class

```
public void tick() {
    if (Engine.key_input.keys[KInput.LEFT]) {
        dx      = -speed;
    animDir = SpriteLoader.L;
    sprite  = SpriteLoader.anim(SpriteLoader.ANIM_PLAYER, animDir);
}
    if (Engine.key_input.keys[KInput.RIGHT]){
        dx      = speed;
        animDir = SpriteLoader.R;
        sprite  = SpriteLoader.anim(SpriteLoader.ANIM_PLAYER, animDir);
}
if (Engine.key_input.keys[KInput.UP]){
        dy      = -speed;
        animDir = SpriteLoader.U;
        sprite  = SpriteLoader.anim(SpriteLoader.ANIM_PLAYER, animDir);
}
if (Engine.key_input.keys[KInput.DOWN]){
         dy         = speed;
         animDir = SpriteLoader.D;
         sprite     = SpriteLoader.anim(SpriteLoader.ANIM_PLAYER, animDir);
}
}
```

// Engine Class

```
public class Engine {
    public Input key_input;
    public Engine() {
        key_input = new Input();
    }

    // add keyListener(Input) to component
}
```

Comment: Step through with a debugger and check whats happening?

Comment: What class contains `keys`, `getKeys()`, and `keyPressed()`? And should `getKeys()` be called `setKeys()` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handler, you are only ever setting the keys[] = true, but you are not ever returning them back to false.

You need to add a keyReleased() method that will un-move all keys that have been released.

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough info from you.  But this is suspicious:

```
public boolean[] keys = new boolean[64]
```

Where is the code that says, "I've used this `keys` value, now I want to ignore it next time"?

Answer (score 1):

In your `tick` method, you only ever check for a "pressed" state, you never reset the movement delta

For example...

```
public void tick() {
    if (Engine.key_input.keys[KInput.LEFT]) {
        dx      = -speed;
    } else {
        dx = 0;
    }
```

I would make determinations of `animDir` and `sprite` based on the `dx` and `dy` variables after you've updated the deltas.

I would also check the left and right, and up and down in a single `if` block...

For example

```
if (Engine.key_input.keys[KInput.LEFT]) {
    dx      = -speed;
} else if (Engine.key_input.keys[KInput.RIGHT]) {
    dx      = speed;
} else{
    dx      = 0;
}
```

This ensures that you don't accidentally reset the movement